# Trigonometric identity expressed as a sum of fractions.

Tags: trigonometry

I am just trying to figure out why this happens:
$$
\cos x + \frac{\sin ^2 x}{\cos x} =  \frac{\cos^2x +\sin^2 x}{\cos x}
$$
How do we get $\cos^2x$ in the numerator on the right-hand side?

I just don't get it.

Comment: Where is the cos^2 in the denominator?

Comment: how about simplifying $2 + {3 \over 2}?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to find the common denominator, then add: $$\cos x + \frac {\sin^2 x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x}\cdot \frac {\cos x}{1} + \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}=\dfrac{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{\cos x} = \dfrac 1{\cos x} = \sec x$$

Comment: this is kinda where I am lost though. common denom would be $$cosx$$, and we're not multiplying or dividing, so I'm confused how we get $$cos^2x$$ up top.

Comment: Ok i think I see it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that is necessarily true:

Multiply through by cos(x)

$\cos^2x+ \sin ^2 x = \cos^3x + \sin^2x$

Using the identity $\cos^2x+ \sin ^2 x = 1$ we get:

$1 = \cos^3x + \sin^2x$

We can rearrange the identity to say $\sin ^2 x = 1 - \cos^2x $ and then substitute to get:

$1 = \cos^3x + (1 - \cos^2x)$

or:

$0 = \cos^3x - \cos^2x $

$\cos^3x = \cos^2x$

which only happens if cos(x) = 1 or cos(x) = 0 [the latter of which can't be true since cos(x) is in the denominator].

So it seems that the original expression is only true if cos(x) = 1.

Comment: um no dude you're incorrect lol, i think you read my problem wrong.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. My computer loaded the problem as cos(x) + sin^2(x)/cos(x) = cos^2(x) + sin^2(x)/cos(x)

Comment: ah then you're right, the person who edited my question edited it wrong. sorry about that! You were right if that was the question though, so ill give you an upvote :)